# Indirect using variable range for Worksheet names

Tags: excel, syntax, excel-formula, worksheet, excel-indirect

I have the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&D1:D2&"'!A1"),E2))
```

Took it from here 
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2541-excel-countif-across-multiple-worksheets.html

Now, i'm making a COUNTA to the D column:

```
=COUNTA(D:D)
```

Which will basically result in me having the number of sheets.

Now, i would like to make the first formula use the result of the second one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&D1:***COUNTA RESULT***&"'!A1"),E2))
```

What is the correct syntax to perform that? Did not manage to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Since worksheets typically have alphabetic names and you were attempting a solution with COUNTA not COUNT, use,

```
D1:index(D:D, match("zzz", D:D))
```

... to describe your range of worksheet names.

However, if the worksheet names are numeric then,

```
D1:index(D:D, match(1e99, D:D))
```

Completed as,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&D1:index(D:D, match("zzz", D:D))&"'!A1"),E2))
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&D1:index(D:D, match(1e99, D:D))&"'!A1"),E2))
```

You could also use `OFFSET(D1, 0, 0, COUNTA(D:D), 1)`. Since you are already using a volatile function with INDIRECT, adding another isn't that big of a deal.

Comment: Note that the latter solution with OFFSET suffers from bad counts due to blank rows.

Comment: Yes, blank rows exists in my program, so it may cause problems.